# How to div start in center like float left or right?

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to div start in center like float right or left but i didn't do this.
Please help me?

**HTML**

```
<div class="conta">
    <div class="box">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.conta{width:100%; position:relative; text-align:center}
.conta .box{float:left; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid #000; margin:5px;}
```

I want to start box in center and inline.

Comment: Please contribute your code

Comment: Did not get your question, you said center and then said like float right or left, if possible post your code here.

Comment: Impossible to answer in the current form.

Comment: ...but that won't stop someone from trying, I guess.

Comment: i got this answer only changed float left. remove float left and replace display inline-block

Answer (score 1):

there is many possible ways.

---

## One

simplest way this is: `margin:0 auto` but you need to have fixed width.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/7L5UB/2)

---

## Two

you can set `display:inline-block;` to inner element and set `text-align:center` to the container.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/7L5UB)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
    text-align:center;
}

div div{
    display:inline-block;
    background:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

---

## Three

set `position:relative` to the container and `position:absolute` to the inner element, then set `left:50%` and `margin-left:-100px` (`margin-left` must be half of the width, in this case `100px`).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/7L5UB/1)

**CSS**

```
div{
    position:relative;
}

div div{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    
    background:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For block-level items, you can use auto margins to do this (when the item is within the document flow. When you float it, position it other than static, you are taking it out of the document flow.)

```
div.my-container { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Will do the trick :)

Comment: `div.my-container` need to have fixed width for that

Comment: Yes it does, but if it doesn't, then it would be taking up the entire width of the parent container anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also,

```
<div id="main" style="text-align:center">
 <div id="inner" style="text-align:left;">
  I want to be center left.......
 </div>
</div>
```

Now main(outer div) aligned to center and the content div(inner) is aligned left in center. This works fine in IE. You should add margin:0 auto; to make this work in all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .myclass{
    margin:0px auto;
text-align:center
    }
```